# How to set a hyperlink in clickable textview? Android Java

Tags: java, android, url, hyperlink, textview

I have a textView with one URL.. But I don't want to show the whole URL but only a few words like: Click here. And when the textview is clicked.. The application need to open te URL "behind" the words Click here..

**For your information:**
The textView is clickable now.
The URL displays correctly.
When the URL is clicked, the browser will start, and load the URL correctly.

I only want to change the text of the link what is visible.

**EDIT:**
Everytime the app restart or reload, the url can be different, so it is nog always the same URL.

Answer (score 5):

use below code :-

```
    android:autoLink="web"
```

like this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_post_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/wall_msg"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using html to achieve this? 
So for example have the following as your text  and then setting

```
String text = "<a href='www.link.com'>Click here</a>";

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the text in your textView to whatever you like. And provide the URL as a variable in your code

EDIT: You say the URL changes: So just save the URL in a variable. Would be interesting how your app receives the new url